# The Regex is return false in any version PHP

Tags: php, regex

I cant find why `/^(\+994|994|0)(50|51|55|70|77)([0-9]{7})$/` type of regex return false in

```
    case "n": // Azerbaijan(for now) phone numbers
      if (!preg_match("/^(\+994|994|0)(50|51|55|70|77)([0-9]{7})$/", $text))
        return false;
```

there.

i put varians is +994555069324 and +9945550693244 and in both variants return false

Comment: The first number [matches](https://regex101.com/r/bqzOJd/1). See https://3v4l.org/bLJVg

Comment: Indeed, the first matches. Perhaps it can be shortened to `^(\+?994|0)(5[015]|7[07])([0-9]{7})$`

Comment: One should match, one shouldn't. If both return false, there is a problem with the code around. Maybe it's a [fallthrough](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Switch_statement#Fallthrough), if you are using switch case?

Comment: Thanks to all of you. I forgot break on case;